# HTML onclick button not calling javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, function

My HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="scorecard.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="scoreButton"><button onclick="javascript: scorecard();">Calculate Score</button></div>
</body>
</html>
```

My Javascript:

```
var a;
var b;
var c;
total;

var scorecard = function() 
    {
    a = prompt("What was your score on a?","A");
    b = prompt("What was your score on b?","B");
    c = prompt("What was your score on c?","C");
    total = (a + b + c);
    document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = a;
    document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = b;
    document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = total;
    };
```

What am I missing? Everything validates yet I can't get it to run in any browser. I'm sure it must be something obvious, however, I have looked at this code and played with it all day and I'm just lost and very frustrated. Any help would be great.

Comment: Can you see any errors in browser's console?

Comment: You have lot of elements missing A, B, C and Total. Also it should be `var total`, instead of just `total`

Comment: change onclick="javascript: scorecard();" to onclick="scorecard();"

Comment: can you put your code online on jsfiddle, codepen or some other place. So that we can run it

Comment: It's as @HimanshuUpadhyay says. The only time you need to add the `javascript:` prefix is if you're doing some linking shenanigans, IIRC. The `on-` methods *always* assume JS is being called.

Comment: No errors are shown in the browser's console that I can see. Yes there are a lot of errors missing as I didn't want to fill the screen with lines and lines of repetitive code. Yes the var total was a typo on my part but that's not really the issue

Comment: @islandeast see the answer.

Answer (score 3):

Multiple issues with your code

- It should be `var total` instead of `total`
- Elements like A, B, C and Total which you are referencing in your code are missing
- You need to convert the values to number as well.

**Demo**

```js
var a;
var b;
var c;
var total;

var scorecard = function() {
  a = +prompt("What was your score on a?", "A");
  b = +prompt("What was your score on b?", "B");
  c = +prompt("What was your score on c?", "C");
  total = (a + b + c);
  document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = a;
  document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = b;
  document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = c;
  document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = total;
};
```

```html
A : <div id="A"></div> <br>
B : <div id="B"></div> <br>
C : <div id="C"></div> <br>

Total : <div id="Total"></div> <br>
<div id="scoreButton"><button onclick="javascript: scorecard();">Calculate Score</button></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Because variable `total` is `undefined`. Make sure your total var is something like `var total` And in addition to that

- There should be `elements with Id's A,B,C,Total` somewhere in document , As you are doing some operation on `DOM` which isn't in `DOM`.
- `parseInt()` if u want to add numbers otherwise it was ok.
  Hope this will work.

```js
var a;
var b;
var c;
var total;

var scorecard = function() 
    {
    a = parseInt(prompt("What was your score on a?","A"));//parseInt() if u want to add numbers otherwise it was ok.
    b = parseInt(prompt("What was your score on b?","B"));
    c = parseInt(prompt("What was your score on c?","C"));
    total = (a + b + c);
    document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = a; //There should be elements with Id's A,B,C,Total somewhere in document.
    document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = b;
    document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = c;
    document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = total;
    };
```

```html
<div id="scoreButton"><button onclick="javascript: scorecard();">Calculate Score</button></div>
 <div id = "A"></div> 
  <div id = "B"></div>
   <div id = "C"></div>
    <div id = "Total"></div>
```

Comment: Before you edited, you missed to convert the values to number. Now working fine. i  upvoted

Answer (score 0):

here you go:

```
<div id="scoreButton"><button onclick="scorecard()">Calculate Score</button></div>    // I have changed syntax of onclick.
```

Comment: That doesn't do anything as I've tried that already. But thanks tho

Comment: 1)You need to convert the values to number  2) need to declare var to total

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
    <script>
        var a;
        var b;
        var c;
        var total;

        function scorecard()
        {

            a = prompt("What was your score on a?", "A");
            b = prompt("What was your score on b?", "B");
            c = prompt("What was your score on c?", "C");
            total = (a + b + c);
            document.getElementById("A").innerHTML = a;
            document.getElementById("B").innerHTML = b;
            document.getElementById("C").innerHTML = c;
            document.getElementById("Total").innerHTML = total;
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
     <div id="scoreButton"><button onclick="scorecard()">Calculate Score</button></div>
     <h3 id="A"></h3>
     <h3 id="B"></h3>
     <h3 id="C"></h3>
</body>
```